# Altering Bootstrap .collapsed to hide menu after link in nav is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button:

```
<button class="logo-navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="bs4navbar" aria-expanded="false">
```

On this button click, which is an SVG logo, the menu appears:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="collapse">
```

When one of the `anchor links` is clicked within the nav, I want the button and navbar to disappear.

I've tried:

```
 $('.navbar-collapse a').click(function (e) {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
  });
```

But it doesn't do anything? How do I go about this?

Comment: The `nav` doesn't appear to have the `.navbar-collapse` class in your example, so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide something, you should use jQuery's .hide() method.
Also you are not getting anchor element right.
Do this-

```
$('#navbar a').click(function (e) {
    $('.logo-navbar-toggle').hide(); //this hides button
    $('#navbar').hide(); //this hides navbar
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function (e) {
    $('.logo-navbar-toggle, .collapse').addClass('d-none');
  });
```